# extract every 1st & 5th line from a file and put them on one line, comma separated with awk

Tags: awk, csv

I have a file, it is a simple music playlist, but the data is as follows

```
Song
Artist
Album
Date Song was added to playlist (mm/dd/yyyy)
Song Duration (mm:ss)
```

What I would like to do is just to get the song and the artist onto one line and export them to a new csv file, lets just say music.csv

so just

```
Song,Artist 
Song,Artist
```

etc etc

I know how to print every nth line, but I could not get it to print every nth + another line

Comment: The 5th line is the duration. I assume you mean the 1st and 2nd of each 5 lines? By the way, is there a specific reason you ask to do that with `awk`? If not, it's better not to specifiy a specific tool to use, because the answers might solve the problem with different tools, for instance like `sed` or even `perl`.

Comment: Don't just provide 1 input record in your example if you can have many as what separates records is often as least as important as the contents of the records, and use representative values in your example, not just the words "Song" and "Artist".

Answer (score 2):

```bash
awk '
    NR % 5 == 1 {printf "%s,", $0}
    NR % 5 == 2
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed`, you could put the 1st of every 5th line into the hold space with `1~5h`.  You would then append the 2nd of every 5th line to the hold space with `H`, get the whole hold space into the buffer with `g`, replace the newline that `sed` delimits the two lines with using a `y` command, and then print the result with `p`:

```bash
sed -n -e '1~5h' -e '2~5 { H; g; y/\n/,/; p; }' file
```

---

You could use `paste`, to format each set of five lines into a single tab-delimited record, use `cut` to extract the 1st and 2nd field of each record, and then replace the delimiting tab with a comma using `tr`:

```bash
paste - - - - - < file | cut -f 1,2 | tr '\t' ','
```

Or, if none of the song and artist fields contain commas,

```bash
paste -d, - - - - - < file | cut -d, -f 1,2
```

---

Transforming each set of five lines into single-line tab-delimited records as above, but then using the CSV-aware Miller tool to extract the first two fields from each record and output CSV:

```bash
paste - - - - - < file | mlr --itsv --ocsv -N cut -f 1,2
```

This would have the additional benefit of automatically quoting any output field containing embedded commas or quotes, making it possible for a CSV-aware parser to read the data properly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in this specific case, is there a difference between the `y` command and the `s` command? I mean, I know that both would do the trick in this case, but would `y` be more efficient in this case than `s`, or are they completely interchangeable here?

Comment: @aviro You would get the same final effect with the `s` command, but the `y` command performs a character by  character replacement, the `s` command does a regular expression match and replacement which may be slightly more "expensive". I tend to use `y` when wanting to change a set of characters to another.

Comment: @aviro I also think the `s` command often get over-used, to the degree that some users think that's all that `sed` can do. It's a sort of "right tool for the job" thing.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done relatively simply with a combination of `sed` to extract the lines and `paste` to join them:

```
$ seq 20 | sed -n 'p;n;p;n;n;n' | paste -d, - -
1,2
6,7
11,12
16,17
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}' file
Song,Artist
Song,Artist
```

The above is guessing that the records in your input are separated by 1 or more empty lines, e,g,:

```
$ cat file
Song
Artist
Album
Date Song was added to playlist (mm/dd/yyyy)
Song Duration (mm:ss)

Song
Artist
Album
Date Song was added to playlist (mm/dd/yyyy)
Song Duration (mm:ss)
```

but it is just a guess since you only provided 1 input record in your example so you haven't shown us yet how records are separated.

Alternatively, if there aren't blank lines or any other separator between your records and they're just 5-line chunks then this may be what you want:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{a[n=NR%5]=$0} !n{print a[1],a[2]}' file
Song,Artist
Song,Artist
```

That 2nd script assumes this input:

```
$ cat file
Song
Artist
Album
Date Song was added to playlist (mm/dd/yyyy)
Song Duration (mm:ss)
Song
Artist
Album
Date Song was added to playlist (mm/dd/yyyy)
Song Duration (mm:ss)
```